# Wordpress Unknown Image Error Provided og:image URL, https://url.lt encountered an unknown error

Tags: wordpress, facebook

Until today everything was working fine. But right now when I share my wordpress site posts on facebook, featured image is not showing.

I tried facebook debugger. I get this information: Provided og:image URL, https://reidasofficial.lt/wp-content/uploads/2023/09/lenkijos-pasienis-1024x576.jpg encountered an unknown error.

Facebook page url: https://reidasofficial.lt/naujienos/pasaulyje/lenkija-ivede-es-draudima-visiems-rusijoje-registruotiems-lengviesiems-automobiliams/

Answer (score 0):

Same issue started today. Getting an Unknown Image Error for a Word Press page debugging. I changed out the original image and changed its link so I could test if FB Debugger picks it up. Debugger scraping is not working properly because every time I scrape for the new image debugger refers to the old image's URL as having an "Unknown Image Error". Hoping FB is on it. The FB social card image used for FB is the recommended 1200x630p @72ppi.